# How to apply Test Driven Development to a new project?

Tags: language-agnostic, tdd

I'm starting a new project and I want to use Test Driven Development, but I having trouble understanding how to write tests when you don't have a data model or interfaces.

IMO, the data model and interfaces should be written.  Then a couple of features should be implemented to verify the data model and interfaces have "matured." (aka changes to either will be minimal).  Then I would write the unit tests.  After that step, I think you can follow TDD.

Is this the correct approach?

On a side note, does it seem like some of these new techniques like TDD don't account or document what to do for new projects.

Comment: A new project is the *easiest* time to apply TDD.

Comment: I would say that statement is very subjective depending on your experience with TDD :)

Comment: Staring at a blank screen with no idea of how to proceed is not the easiest time to *learn* TDD. Watch the screencast demo below.

Comment: I think you should set all of your opinions aside, follow TDD to the book, then decide what you like and don't. It's best just to try and experience for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like they say, "start with a failing unit test".

- You don't need a data model until and unless it's needed in order to fix a failing unit test.
- You don't need interfaces until they're necessary (to fix a failing unit test)

Maybe if you give an example of an application, we can help you find the first few failing tests.

Comment: I'm still a little shaky as to how you write a unit test for something when you don't have objects to set and check.  Does this mean you write a skeleton class and then write the unit test for that skeleton?

Comment: @daub: no, you write the test before the skeleton class. You create pieces of the class only when the test needs them.

Comment: I think thats why they call it test `driven` development. You know, with the tests driving you to write the code.

Answer (score 3):

TDD does NOT constitute a multi-day process of writing tests then writing code to make those tests pass. TDD is about incorporating test effort in a parallel manner with the development effort.

Writing a few tests to address a potential class then writing the class would be an example of a parallel effort. Writing tests to address a module composed of a multitude of classes then writing the classes to make these tests pass is not a parallel effort and should be avoided since refactoring is inevitable throughout development.

Comment: I think this is a key point. This is a highly iterative and interactive process. It is all about short feedback loops.

Answer (score 2):

You get a general idea of the classes you need then you write a test, watch it fail, make it pass, and repeat. you might realize you need to move methods around or create new classes but thats part of the process.

See this video for a live demo
http://katas.softwarecraftsmanship.org/?p=80

Comment: Although the screencast was interesting, the language he was using threw me off a bit.

Comment: @daub815 He has the same project in several languages screencasted.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point is that when you write a test, it's going to fail.  You don't need data models or interfaces to write a failing test.

http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Red-Green-Refactor.html